# Room: Passing Values for Parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

In my room application I have an error:

No value passed for parameter 'pb_value'

No value passed for parameter 'pb_date'

No value passed for parameter 'pb_details'

However, when I pass in these values so I have 4 values instead of 1 , I get an message saying:

:app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses 26 ms
Execute taskAction  12 ms.

I can't pass in these values without getting a second error. How would I fix this?

SOLVED: I removed a couple of dependencies and was then able to pass in the values without getting the second error.

MainActivity

```
if (requestCode == newPbActivityRequestCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            intentData?.let { data ->
                val pb = Pb(data.getStringExtra(NewPbActivity.EXTRA_REPLY))
                pbViewModel.insert(pb)
```

Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "pb_table")
data class Pb(@PrimaryKey val pb: String,
              @ColumnInfo(name = "value")val pb_value: Double,
              @ColumnInfo(name = "date")val pb_date: Int,
              @ColumnInfo(name = "details")val pb_details: String)
```

Comment: `:app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses 26 ms Execute taskAction 12 ms.` that's just a message, what is the actual error?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I've just managed to fix the problem. By deleting a couple of dependencies that weren't needed I am able to pass in the values and then I don't have the second error.

Answer (score -1):

Android database execution needs to be run on background thread. So make sure you put your insert code in background thread. I often use RxJava for this

```
Completable.fromCallable { pbViewModel.insert(pb) }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidScheduler.mainThread())
    .subscribe()
```